# extracting meta info from a table psql using information_schema

Tags: postgresql

How do I extract following meta information from a psql table. column_name, data_type, char_max_length,numeric_precision,constraint_type, constraint_reference, check_clause .In short the information that we have got by this query "\d table_name".

Answer (score 0):

Start `psql` with the `-E` flag, and take note of the queries it generates when you issue `\d table_name` -- you'll need to reproduce many or most of those queries in order to get all the metadata you're asking for.